# minimal elements in heap for Python

Tags: python, heap

Want to get the minimal elements for a min heap in Python using heapq, here is my code and wondering if using h[0] is the correct way or a more elegant public API for heapq? I tried to find is there is an API to get minimal element of a heap, but cannot find it out.

BTW, using Python 2.

```
import heapq

def heapMin(iterable):
   h = []
   for value in iterable:
       heapq.heappush(h, value)
   return h[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":

   print heapMin([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0])
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Maybe `heapq.nsmallest(1, h)`?

Comment: Not sure why `h[0]` is not elegant for you. Even docs mention it https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop

Comment: @vaultah it seems that this will do unnecessary work. See https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#l221

Comment: @Alik, what specific unnecessary work do you mean?

Comment: @Alik, thanks for pointing out the document and if you could add a reply, I will mark it as an Answer to benefit other people. :)

Comment: @LinMa `heapq.nsmallest(1, h)` performs a lot of work internally. Take a look at sources of `heapq` module I've referenced earlier. It doesn't make sense to use it if `h` was already heapified

Comment: @Alik, thanks a lot. Would you add a reply, I will mark it as answered to benefit other people. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your iterable list into a heap in one go, use this. Instead of looping, use the `heapify()` function and the `heappop(iterable)` should return you the first index (least number)

```
heapq.heapify(iterable)
print heapq.heappop(iterable)
```

Comment: `heapq.heappop(h)` actually modifies `h`, while `h[0]` doesn't

Comment: Yes, sameera, heappop will modify as @Alik mentioned. I need just read the smallest element without modify the heap itself.

Comment: Yeah true! After it returns the first element, it tries to `reheapify` the list again! Thanks anyway @Alik and @linma!

Comment: @sameerasy, thanks for all the help and mark your reply as an answer. :)